# Next/Previous Keyboard Toolbar iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

Currently, I am trying to set the next/previous buttons on my keyboard toolbar to the new, sleek iOS 7 back button/forward buttons that get put in navigation controllers to go back. Here is what I am trying. How can I use the system bar button item instead of the boring static text?

```
[self setToolbar:[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame]];
        [self.toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
        [self.toolbar setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
        [self addSubview:self.toolbar];

        [self setSegmentedControl:[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[ NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Previous", @"BSKeyboardControls", @"Previous button title."),
                                                                               NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Next", @"BSKeyboardControls", @"Next button title.") ]]];
```

Here is what it looks like now:

[image]

Here is what I want it to look like:
[image]

Any ideas on how to access those system items without actually using images? I know its the exact iOS 7 back bar button item, I just don't know how to access it in a tool bar. I've searched everywhere. If it helps, i'm using BSKeyboardControls.

EDIT: To make it look exactly like the second image, use the images provided by Joshua, and save them as back@2x.png, and forward@2x.png into your xcode proj. Use Chun's code, but make sure to call the method for getting the images like this: imageNamed:@"back", and not @"back@2x". You now have iOS 7 back and forward buttons :)

EDIT2: To get it to look exactly like the next/previous arrow buttons use the following customizations in the correct implementation methods:

```
[self.segmentedControl setWidth:50 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[self.segmentedControl setWidth:38 forSegmentAtIndex:1];

negativeSeparator.width = -19;
```

EDIT3: The toolbar with the < > arrows comes by default with all UIWebViews, and it appears when you tap a textfield.

If anyone is interested in a sample project, let me know, and i'll upload a link!

EDIT4: As of May 24, 2014, BSKeyboardControls now has this functionality by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Download latest files from: https://github.com/simonbs/BSKeyboardControls

2) Import the images for back/next buttons. These can be whatever you want and you can set the appropriate sizes so that they look good. Joshua has a good set. I have mine saved as "keyboardBack.png" and "keyboardForward.png"

3) In BSKeyboardControls.m, update initWithFields:fields. Here you can do some customization like setting the width of your back/next buttons. I removed the Done button here too to follow your screenshot but you can add it back.

```
- (id)initWithFields:(NSArray *)fields
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 44.0f)])
    {
        // Creates toolbar
        [self setToolbar:[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame]];
        [self.toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
        [self.toolbar setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
        [self addSubview:self.toolbar];

        // Import images
        UIImage *backImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"keyboardBack"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        UIImage *forwardImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"keyboardForward"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

        // Create segmentedcontrol
        self.segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[backImage, forwardImage]];
        self.segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        // Set button widths
        [self.segmentedControl setWidth:50 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
        [self.segmentedControl setWidth:50 forSegmentAtIndex:1];

        // Other BSKeyboardControls stuff
        [self.segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [self.segmentedControl setMomentary:YES];
        [self.segmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:BSKeyboardControlsDirectionPrevious];
        [self.segmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:BSKeyboardControlsDirectionNext];
        [self setSegmentedControlItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.segmentedControl]];
        [self setVisibleControls:(BSKeyboardControlPreviousNext)];
        [self setFields:fields];
    }

    return self;
}
```

4) The left padding on the toolbar is a bit too much, so you can fix it by adding a negative separator in toolbarItems: in BSKeyboardControls.m:

```
- (NSArray *)toolbarItems
{
    NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3];
    if (self.visibleControls & BSKeyboardControlPreviousNext)
    {
        UIBarButtonItem *negativeSeperator = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
                                                                                           target:nil
                                                                                           action:nil];
        negativeSeperator.width = -12;

        [items addObject:negativeSeperator];
        [items addObject:self.segmentedControlItem];

    }

    if (self.visibleControls & BSKeyboardControlDone)
    {
        [items addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil]];
        [items addObject:self.doneButton];
    }

    return items;
}
```

Note: I probably don't have the button widths and paddings to the exact specs, but you can tweak it to your liking!

Comment: Wonderful, in depth answer! Great job! If you had answered a bit earlier I would have given you the bounty too!

Answer (score 21):

These are the images used in toolbar, e.g. the back and forward button images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am assuming these are the x2? Do you have the x1 as well?

Comment: @Arian I'm afraid not, you should just be able to shrink them by half to  give still a fairly good 1x image.

Answer (score 9):

Use the icons shared by Joshua and then try with below piece of code and you will be good to go. I have not added the done button here.

```
UIImage *backImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"backImage"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIImage *forwardImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"forward"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
self.segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[backImage, forwardImage]];
[self.segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlChangedState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
self.segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIBarButtonItem *aSegmentedControlBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.segmentedControl];
[self setItems:@[aSegmentedControlBarButtonItem, self.flexibleSpace]];
```

Comment: What is the parameter type to `segmentedControlChangedState:`? `UISegmentedControl`?

Comment: Yes. `- (void)segmentedControlChangedState:(UISegmentedControl *)iSender`

Comment: `segmentedControlStyle` is deprecated, now has no effect.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind living on the edge you could use Apple's undocumented system items to achieve the iOS 7 look. Here are left and right bar button items.

```
    [self setDoneButton:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:105 target:nil action:nil]];
    [self setDoneButton:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:106 target:nil action:nil]];
```

Source: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIBarButtonItem

Comment: Is it allowed for App Store apps?

Comment: The correct answer is this since apple handles this kind of images in its own way. We should stick with it to prevent our apps look absurd after ios updates.

Comment: How can I accomplish this using Swift?

Comment: This doesn't work in Xcode 7.3/Swift 2.2: it won't let you use an integer in the `initWithBarButtonSystemItem` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this great [tool](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) by @iftekhar and customise `IQSegmentedNextPrevious` according to your need for giving images instead of next previous button.

Answer (score 1):

Using Xcode 7.3, you can also just enter a symbol as the *title* for the Bar Item. This works both in code and in Interface Builder:

- Place your cursor where you want the symbol to appear (eg, `title` box in IB or within quotes in code).
- In Xcode's menu, click Edit, then Emoji & Symbols. (Alternatively, press control-command-space to bring up the list of characters.)
- In the search box, type *less* or *greater*.
- Then, select the symbol you want.

The less-than and greater-than symbols are colored blue in the toolbar by default.

In code:

```
backButton.title = "＜"
```

In IB:

[image: control-command-click to bring up Emoji & Symbols]

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `https://github.com/simonbs/BSKeyboardControls`

But it uses the segmented control which got flattened in iOS 7.

Edit:
Just change the text of the segments:

```
  [self setSegmentedControl:[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"<",@">") ]]];
```

This may not be the most elegant.  (Not even sure this exact code compiles, but you see the point)

Comment: That is what I am using. I am just curious on how to change the segmentedcontrol to just the <> symbols.

Comment: Do you mean, just change the text on the source of the BSKeyboard code:

Comment: No, I mean actually use the iOS 7 arrows. Like the ones on navigation items.