# Next/Previous Keyboard Toolbar iOS7 in mono

Tags: c#, ios7, mono, xamarin

i know this question is already being asked before in objective c,but i need to create in mono/xamarin ios.

i found one question in this link [Next/Previous Keyboard Toolbar iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969364/next-previous-keyboard-toolbar-ios7).

Does anyone can suggest me any example to do this? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hi. Check out the following article. It explains how to add custom `InputAccessoryView` (the bar above the keyboard with custom buttons): http://nnish.com/2013/12/02/adding-custom-buttons-to-ios-keyboard-in-c-xamarin/

Comment: If you want you can create your own answer (after a few days) and accept it. This way the question will be answered if someone will encounter the same problem in the future, you will get some reputation and you will have a documented solution for your own problem :-)